# Magento 2 get Orders from last 24 hours

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, sales

i need to extract the list of all orders executed in the last 24 hours, from now.
I have a code almost working but not every orders is processing.

The cronjob runs smoothly but i miss the last 3/4 orders. Maybe i have missed something with the date?

```
public function exportOrders($timestamp)
   {
       $date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-24 hours');
       $date2 = (new \DateTime())->modify('now');

       $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
           ->addFilter(
               'created_at',
               $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
               'gt'
           )->addFilter(
               'created_at',
               $date2->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
               'lteq'
               )
           ->addFilter('status', ['processing'], 'in')
           ->create();

       $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

       /**
        * @var $order OrderInterface
        */
       $ordersData =[];
       $itemsData =[];
       if ($orders->getTotalCount() > 0) {
           foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
               $items = $order->getAllItems();
               $postCode = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
               $method = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
               try {
                   $zip = $this->validateZipCode($postCode);

                   if (is_array($zip)) {
                       if (isset($zip['zipitem_id'])) {
                           $zipObject = $this->zipcode->load($zip['zipitem_id']);
                           $method = $zipObject->getData('area');
                       }
                   }
               } catch (\Exception $e) {
                   var_dump($e->getMessage());
               }

               $ordersData[] = [
                   'entity_id c(20)' => $order->getEntityId(),
                   'coupon_code c(20)' => $order->getCouponCode() ?? "NA",
                   'shipping_description c(50)' => $order->getShippingDescription() ?? "nA",
                   'customer_id c(20)' => $order->getCustomerId() ?? "NA",
                   'grand_total c(20)' => $order->getBaseGrandTotal() ?? 0,
                   'shipping_amount c(20)' => $order->getBaseShippingAmount() ?? 0,
                   'shipping_tax_amount c(20)' => $order->getBaseShippingTaxAmount() ?? 0,
                   'discount_amount c(20)' => $order->getDiscountAmount() ?? 0,
                   'customer_is_guest c(1)' => $order->getCustomerIsGuest() ?? 0,
                   'billing_address_id c(20)' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getEntityId() ?? 0,
                   'increment_id c(20)' => $order->getIncrementId() ?? 0,
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151134/get-orders-items-from-last-24-hours-in-magento